# Fill colour vector based on unique columns

Tags: r

I am using c3 to plot some lines. If two lines are exactly the same C3 overwrites them and uses *different* colours in the legend. I would like the colours in the legend to be the same.

Here are some examples

```
# If two lines are identical, colour them the same

library(tidyverse)
library(c3)

# Dark red, blue, orange, black, purple
cbpal <- c("#800000", "#4363d8", "#f58231", "#000000", "#dcbeff")

# Companies A and B are should be dark red. Companies C and D should be blue
df1 <- tibble(
  date = seq(as.Date("2020-01-01"), by = "month", length.out = 4),
  comp_A = rep(4, 4),
  comp_B = rep(4, 4),
  comp_C = rep(2, 4),
  comp_D = rep(2, 4)
)

# Company A and B should be dark red. Companies C, D, E, should all be blue
df2 <- tibble(
  date = seq(as.Date("2020-01-01"), by = "month", length.out = 4),
  comp_A = rep(4, 4),
  comp_B = rep(4, 4),
  comp_C = rep(3, 4),
  comp_D = rep(3, 4),
  comp_E = rep(3, 4)
)

# Company A and B should be dark red. Companies C, D, should all be blue
# Companies E, F, should all be orange
df3 <- tibble(
  date = seq(as.Date("2020-01-01"), by = "month", length.out = 4),
  comp_A = rep(4, 4),
  comp_B = rep(4, 4),
  comp_C = rep(3, 4),
  comp_D = rep(3, 4),
  comp_E = rep(2, 4),
  comp_F = rep(2, 4)
)

c3(df1)
df1_pal <- c("#800000", "#800000", "#4363d8","#4363d8")
c3(df1) %>% 
  c3_color(df1_pal)

c3(df2)
df2_pal <- c("#800000", "#800000", "#4363d8","#4363d8", "#4363d8")
c3(df2) %>% 
  c3_color(df2_pal)

c3(df3)
df3_pal <- c("#800000", "#800000", "#4363d8","#4363d8", "#f58231", "#f58231")
c3(df3) %>% 
  c3_color(df3_pal)
```

In the first data frame, there are 4 lines, but comp_A and comp_B are the same and comp_C and comp_D are the same. To create the colour vector I take the first colour from my colour blind palette, `#800000`, and colour comp_A with it. I notice that comp_B is the same and make it the same colour, `#800000`. comp_C is different and so I reach into `cbpal` again and grab the second colour. Eventually, I end up with the colour palette, `df1_pal <- c("#800000", "#800000", "#4363d8","#4363d8")`, as shown.

There are two more examples. In all cases, the data frames will be ordered in descending order of y-axis value.

How do I programmatically create these colour vectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hash of each column can be used to map the column to a color.

`get_cols` gets the hash of each column. The hash is mapped to an index which is used with `cbpal` to get the colour.

```
get_cols <- function(df) {
  hashes <-
    df %>%
    select(-date) %>%
    map_chr(digest::digest)
  
  cbpal[match(hashes, unique(hashes))]
}
```

```
get_cols(df1)
#> [1] "#800000" "#800000" "#4363d8" "#4363d8"

get_cols(df2)
#> [1] "#800000" "#800000" "#4363d8" "#4363d8" "#4363d8"

get_cols(df3)
#> [1] "#800000" "#800000" "#4363d8" "#4363d8" "#f58231" "#f58231"
```